# show that $f$ is not integrable on $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, real-numbers, riemann-sum

Define $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$f(x):= 
\begin{cases}
e^{x}, \ x \in \mathbb{Q}\\ 
e^{-x}, \ x\in \mathbb{Q}^{c}\\
\end{cases}$

show that $f$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$.

I just started on analysis and though I'm somewhat familiar on showing a function is integrable, I'm find myself kind of stuck when trying to prove the opposite. I wanted to make use of the negation of the definition of darboux integrable, but do not know how to proceed. Any help or insights is deeply appreciated.

Comment: **HINT**: Can you show that every lower sum is at most $\int_0^1 e^{-x}\,dx$ and every upper sum is at least $\int_0^1 e^x\,dx$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: argue via upper and lower Riemann sums, using the that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense.

(The upper Riemann sum will be the integral over $e^x$, the lower the one for $e^{-x}$.)